# Proper way to test REST API (php)

Tags: php, rest, phpunit, swagger, behat

Never thought that testing a REST API will be that difficult, when I was doing fullstack, I was dreaming about go to REST so I don't have mess with html and all that stuff, only Behat saves me, it helps a lot when comes to testing html pages.

But when it comes to testing an API I have a headache. let's say I have some resource, like list of user's conversations.

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/api/v1/conversations"
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Lana Smith",
        "avatarUrl": "/static/avatars/597bd819d90f2568107586.png",
        "createdAt": "2017-01-05T00:00:00+03:00",
        "updatedAt": "2017-01-05T00:00:00+03:00",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "/api/v1/conversations/4"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Ian North [Support Agent]",
        "avatarUrl": "/static/avatars/default.png",
        "createdAt": "2017-01-04T01:00:00+03:00",
        "updatedAt": "2017-01-04T01:02:00+03:00",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "/api/v1/conversations/3"
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

And as a decent human being I have Swagger documentation, that states that this particular resource should look like this, those fields are optional, those are of type integer, there you have a relation and so on and so forth

But:

- how do I test that structure IS as swagger docs says it is
- how do I
  test that data is correct (like that user has exact his
  conversations, not someone else's, and correct number of them)

I have few approaches in my mind:

- Just test whole payload of JSON hardcoded in test against one that came from response. The difficulty here that sometimes I don't know the exact values for example createdAt/updatedAt generated during fixtures loading, avatar urls are always random, unless default and so on.
- Use phpunit and test everything manually like: assertPropertyCount($response, 2, '_embedded.items) then assertProperty equals(...)

How do I do it that way that it doesn't take 5 times longer that writing production code

Comment: You can test the entire `JSON` at once only if you can predict the values for changing parts else do validations by parts: has +1 messages, has only messages from, see sent message identified by generated random string and date etc.. You should define some test cases first to know what validations you will need.Plan first. Use Guzzle + goutte and don't forget to add `@api` tag on your feature. As for assertions you can choose any way, i would define my own with basic php methods.

Comment: If you can build on top of Swagger/OAI, you can take libraries who can do part of your testing work, e.g. https://github.com/nabbar/SwaggerValidator-PHP

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar that much with PHP and stack of tools that surround it, but in general for API testing as well as any testing it can be indeed much more than production code, and depends on how your JSON is generated, meaning the logic behind it, you can write quite smart tests.

For example, let's assume you have an API endpoint which is getting JSON input and generating JSON as output, that means that obviously, you know the logic of it. So, what you can do is, have one test JSON in your code and matching test JSON as output and during testing call API in test mode and post JSON and assert it vs output JSON, in that case, all dynamic fields can be matched.

Apart from that, it really does not matter in which language is API, for testing it in real time on test environment or staging, you can use tools like [REST Assured](http://rest-assured.io/) or [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate), or much much more. I believe there are tools/frameworks that are integrating really well with PHP also.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it with apitest

```
{
  test1: {
    req: {

    },
    res: {
      body: {
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "/api/v1/conversations"
          }
        },
        "_embedded": {
          "items": [ @partial
            {
              "id": 0, @type
              "name": "", @type
              "avatarUrl": `/^\/static\/avatars\/\w+\.png$/.test($)`, @eval
              "createdAt": "isDate($)", @eval
              "updatedAt": "isDate($)", @eval
              "_links": {
                "self": {
                  "href": `/^\/api\/v1\/conversations\/\d+/.test($)`, @eval
                }
              }
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Apitest is declarative api testing tool with JSON-like DSL.

See https://github.com/sigoden/apitest